# Is it possible to add Owl Carousel 2 on a website which already uses multiple owl Carousel 1 sliders?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress, owl-carousel

I have used Owl Carousel 1 on many of my websites(wordpress custom plugins) and now I want to build new slider plugin using Owl Carousel 2. The problem is I cannot get rid of my old plugins as this is the add on to those plugins.

Is there a way where I can load both version of Owl Carousel on the same websites and not see any conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version 2 is a beta version. so it may conflict in some cases. 
you can use version 2 as is. there is no need to load either of two plugins.